# How to make backlink (href) to another html file?

Tags: html

i have problem with backlink. I did translation and i have now:

```
Main catalog: Website, 
inside two catalogs: Eng, Fra, 
inside Eng: eng.html, inside Fra: fra.html
```

I need to change page when i click on button change language. Something like that:

```
href="../eng.html"
```

doesn't work. Both catalogs are on the same level. How can i write it correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your files are in different catalogs, which you forgot to place in access path.

English to French, place it in fra.html:
`<a href="../Eng/eng.html"></a>`

French to English, place in eng.html:
`<a href="../Fra/fra.html"></a>`